# Locating lower level templates

Tags: python, templates, bottle

Hi I am having problems with the template using Bottle

my folder structure is this:

```
|views  
 --main.tpl
 --|blog
    --home.tpl
```

what I want to do is this:

```
def home():
    return template('blog/home')
```

but it won't work

I can get it to work just calling the following:

```
def home():
    return template('main')
```

But I want to be-able to have many different folders
I understand that I will still need to keep unique names because of the caching 
and please don't say use a different framework as this is not my choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing the template_lookup argument to the template function.  template_lookup overrides the defaults .views path when looking for the template.  However I believe this will only work if the name of the tempalte is not in the views folder.  So if you had a /views/main.tpl and a /blog/main.tpl it would not work, every template needs a unique name.  This is needed because bottle will only lookup search for tempaltes if it hasn't found it before and stores the found ones in a dict with the tempalte name as the key.  so if the templates have the same name it would use the first one.

```
return template("home", template_lookup="full_path_to/views/blog/"
```